# AppleScript: loop over application windows; bring each to front & trigger action in other app?

Tags: macos, applescript

## Short Version

I want to write some AppleScript which iterates over an application's (non-minimised) windows and for each of them, brings it to the front and triggers something in another app, BTT (which will move the window). The aim is to move all windows of the app to the same place. The moving part is handled (by BTT), I just need help with making this happen to *all* the app's windows.

## Long Version

(This question involves [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) but it's not really about that - I think - and I suspect you don't need to know anything about BTT to answer...)

I'm trying to write an AppleScript script which (when I boil it down to the simplest version possible) activates some app, and loops over all its windows, triggering a BetterTouchTool "named trigger" for each window. The job of the named trigger is to move the current window to some location, but the details of that don't matter.

This feels to me like it should be straightforward, but I don't seem to be able to find the right approach.  I've tried cargo-culting it but I'm not getting anywhere (other than a suspicion I'll need to involve "System Events")... I'm an experienced programmer but I've never gone deep into AppleScript and find its way of doing things rather weird/confusing.

What I've got working so far is a version which doesn't loop over the windows, so it just hits the "first" one (in some sense of "first", which seems to be "most recently active for this app").

For example, the following works.  (I've hard coded it here to VSCode, though in the full thing I'm trying to write, it iterates over a list of app names and the triggers to run for them.)

```
on run
    if application "Visual Studio Code" is running then
        tell application "Visual Studio Code" to activate
        tell application "BetterTouchTool"
            trigger_named "Move window: monitor 4k: core"
        end tell
    end if
end run
```

So that activates VSCode, then tells BTT to run a named trigger to move the current window to some position on the screen. The effect is that the most recently used VSCode window gets moved.

OK, not a bad start, but I want to do this for *all* VSCode windows (or ideally, all non-minimised ones on currently visible desktops).

BTT's AppleScript interface doesn't seem to support targetting particular windows - it just works on whatever app/window is active, so I need to somehow activate/bring to front (?) the window *then* call the BTT trigger.

I guess I need *something* like this (ignoring, for now, the problem of omitting minimised windows):

```
on run
    if application "Visual Studio Code" is running then
        tell application "Visual Studio Code" to activate
        repeat with app_window in windows
            bring_window_to_front()
            tell application "BetterTouchTool"
                trigger_named "Move window: monitor 4k: core"
            end tell
        end repeat
    end if
end run
```

... where I don't know how to do the `bring_window_to_front()` part!

(Also not considered here: other desktops; but I can live without that I think.)

Could someone point me in the right direction? All help appreciated!

## Summary

I want to:

- Given an application identified by a given name...
- get all of its windows and loop over them, and for each:
- activate/bring that window to the front (provided it's not minimised) and...
- tell BetterTouchTool to run the trigger with the given name.

## Context

- MacOS Mojave 10.14.5
- BetterTouchTouch 3.072 (not that I think this makes any difference)

Answer (score 4):

Any scriptable app — I'm assuming "Visual Studio Code" is scriptable (has a scripting dictionary) from what you wrote — should respond to this code:

```
on run
    if application "Visual Studio Code" is running then
        tell application "Visual Studio Code" to activate
        set wList to every window whose visible is true
        repeat with app_window in wList
            set index of app_window to 1
            delay .5
            tell application "BetterTouchTool"
                trigger_named "Move window: monitor 4k: core"
            end tell
        end repeat
    end if
end run
```

- The `... whose visible is true` part of line 4 excludes hidden or minimized windows.
- The `set index of ...` command in line 6 cycles each window to the front.

`index` and `visible` are part of the standard Window properties that all AppleScript developers are supposed to implement, so unless the app designers are complete amateurs they should 'just work.' Look at the scripting dictionary in Script Editor to be sure. Sometimes AppleScript designers add special commands that are useful, or change the names of standard properties (possibly just to be annoying).

I'm not sure if the `delay .5` in line 7 is needed. I threw it in to be overly-sure the window was frontmost before the BTT call.

Don't use GUI-scripting or System Events unless the app is non-scriptable. GUI-scripting is extremely useful when it is *needed*, but if the app has a scripting dictionary using that will be far more efficient and reliable. GUI-scripting is clunky, slow, and subject to unpredictable disruptions. But if you do need to use it, the code is similar.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Visual Studio Code"
        set frontmost to true
        set wlist to every window
        repeat with aWindow in wlist
            tell aWindow
                perform action "AXRaise"
                delay .5
                tell application "BetterTouchTool"
                    trigger_named "Move window: monitor 4k: core"
                end tell
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need System Events. It can give you all running and visible processes (i.e. = applications) and for each, list of windows.

Even more, you can then directly update position of each window. Here is sample script which gets all open windows of all applications and move the position of the "Library" Window of "Script Editor" (I open it for my tests):

```
tell application "System Events"
set theProcesses to application processes whose visible is true
repeat with aProcess in theProcesses -- loop thru all visible processes

    set allWindows to every window of aProcess
    repeat with myWindow in allWindows -- for each process, look for all windows

        set Pname to name of aProcess
        set Wname to name of myWindow
        if Pname = "Script Editor" and Wname = "Library" then
            set position of myWindow to {400, 900}
        end if

    end repeat -- window loop
end repeat -- process loop
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks - but I don't want to position the window using AppleScript, I explicitly want to do it via BTT so I'm not repeating my location specifications. So the question remains, how to activate/bring to front each of those windows so that the BTT trigger will operate on it?

Also, this approach doesn't let me target applications by name (which I need because different apps need different BTT triggers to be fired).

And finally, this approach seems to be restricting to visible processes rather than non-minimised windows - though maybe I can work that out. Thanks though, may be of some help.

Comment: Sorry. I missed the point BTT. The name of each process is in variable Pname. Using that name you can address the relevant application. To make a window the active one, action AXRaise" mentioned by Ted is the solution. Please note that the script restricted to "visible" processes to select only Applications running. However, I did not restrict the loop over windows to only visible windows; therefore the minimized windows are also considered.